# Activerecord statement "ambiguous" but doesn't seem to be incorrect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've done this type of statement a bunch of times but it is now telling me that the statement is ambiguous. Here is the error:

```
Mysql::Error: Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous: SELECT     COUNT(DISTINCT `tasks`.`id`) AS count_id FROM       `tasks`  LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `tasks`.`author_id` WHERE     (created_at >= '2012-01-14 18:38:29')
```

here is the statement:

```
Task.count(:conditions => ["created_at > ?", 1.month.ago])
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You might have defined a default scope, and included `users` in that. Something to the effect of: `default_scope includes(:users)`

Comment: Sorry, why does the default_scope includes(:users) cause the ambiguous query? I bumped into this as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
Task.count(:conditions => ["tasks.created_at > ?", 1.month.ago])
```

each of your tables likely has a created_at so you've got to specify which table you want to target in your query.